# What kind of fossil or creature is this from? Found in the ocean

Tags: geobiology

[image]

I found this in the waters of the Dominican Republic -- any idea of what it belongs to/how old it might be? I thought it might be a tooth, but I tried matching to existing marine life in the area but could not find a definite match. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure my tag change is any better, as I'm not sure it comes close to qualifying as a fossil?  May be some question of whether it's on topic here or on biology?  An interesting gray area.

Comment: Thanks Jeopardy, I think you're right with the tag change, either way like you said not sure not sure :)

Comment: I'm pretty certain that's not a tooth.

Comment: Hi Spencer-thanks for your suggestion--if not a tooth do you know what it is? It has 'ridges' along the side of it as well--probably about 20 or so

Comment: Hi all..I also deferred this to my cousin who is in brachiopod studies...he suggested that this might actually be a 'piece' of an echinoderm? After his suggestion i theorize that this might possibly be the arm of a starfish?

Comment: Not a tooth and also not a fossil, try asking in the biology stack. first impression is either a fish or echinoderm ossicle.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Thanks for your help everyone--after your tips I did some sleuthing, and in the included picture/top right in black and white, that looks EXACTLY like what i found, the 'arm' of some kind of starfish.